# How to get page title in watch:$route for Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Nuxt/Vue based app receives in watch:$route as well as in this.$route name, path, but never meta.
E.g. I have a page Foo with

```
export default {
    ...
    head(){
        return{
            title: 'Foo'
        }
    },
    meta: {
        title: 'Foo'
    }
}
```

In the layout

```
export default {

    created() {    
        console.log( this.$route );
    }

    watch:{
        $route ({ path, name, meta }){
            console.log( meta );
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, it's available in middleware

```
export default function ({ store, route }) {
    console.log( route );
}
```

I can populate store from middleware and rely on it in the app, but it's doesn't look as a good solution to me.

Is there any decent way to receive page (route) meta with Router events?
Actually what I need is page title on internal (SPA) navigation events.

Comment: maybe `title: this.$route.meta.title` work

Comment: nope, this.$route.meta is empty

Comment: Is there still no answer to this? I tried some other things but it seems too much for just setting a page title...

Comment: FYI, route meta is different than page meta

Answer (score 4):

Nuxt has a plugin called [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) which comes installed by default. It's an HTML Metadata manager for Vue.js.

Read the [guide](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/) because using it can be very helpful and allows you to follow best practices regarding HTML meta, like current page title, but basically you can use something like:

```js
// in the layout root component, use a computed like this to display the page title:
export default {
  computed: {
    title(ctx) {
      return ctx.$root.$meta().refresh().metaInfo.titleChunk
    },
  }
}
// in each page component, set the page title, using `vue-meta` conventions:
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Dashboard',
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Nuxt.js uses vue-meta to update the document head and meta attributes of your application.
https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#meta-resume

Comment: While the above solution works, sometimes I got SSR errors, because `refresh()` needs access to the DOM. I don't know why this is normal behaviour but Nuxt, during SSR, evaluates computed values (or seems to). My own solution to a problem similar to yours was to use the Nuxt event bus to update template title: using `this.$nuxt.emit` on page component `mounted` to signal the new title and `this.$nuxt.on` on the template component `created` to set the local data that the page title is bound to.